# Flexible PVC to flexible metal conduit connector

Tags: wiring

I had planned to install a new run using flexible PVC conduit, but discovered a section of metal conduit already in place within a wall I can reuse. Is there a way to directly connection PVC and metal flexible conduit without needing a junction box?

I'm not adverse to using a junction box, just thought a direct connector would save time & effort.

Thanks.

i.e. connecting these two conduits...

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the reasoning behind using LFNC instead of ENT (smurf tube) for the new run?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can convert from liquid tight to metal flex you need a end for each and a coupling to connect the two. If both are 1/2” for example a standard 1/2” conduit coupling Will allow the two to be connected without a box.